# Could anyone help me with this typical question?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

If $\frac{a}{(bc-a^2)^2} + \frac{b}{(ac-b^2)^2} + \frac{c}{(ab-c^2)^2} = 0$, then the value of $1+\frac{a}{bc-a^2} + \frac{b}{ac-b^2} + \frac{c}{ab-c^2}$ is $\cdots$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1065429p4626867